# solr vs xapian: which one gives you the most meaningful results?

Tags: search-engine, solr, xapian

I am currently using whoosh to dev a website, and I'll need to choose something more powerful once the website will be in production.

If anyone of you used both of these engines, which one gave you the most meaningful results one the long road?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Solr is the best option. Its well documented and the community is huge. Almost a year ago I benchmarked Xapian vs Solr:

My dataset had +8000 emails:

#### Solr

- index time: 3s
- index size: 5.2mb

#### Xapian

- index time: 30s
- index size: 154mb

Another great reading about benchmarks between Xapian and Solr is this document: [Cross-instance Search System - Search Engine Comparison](http://paginas.fe.up.pt/~ei04073/Search_Engine_Comparison.pdf)

Comment: Although that document is from 2004 so rather likely to be out of date.

Comment: I've been workin with solr for one year now; it's a great product, but the documentation is crappy.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question - which was about which one gives more *meaningful* results...

Comment: Providing the timings and sizes for index generation is nice, but not nearly enough to make a sound decision with. How fast do actual searches compare? I personally chose Xapian because it is comparably just as fast and doesn't add another point of failure (another daemon) in the data flowing through your application.